# AP Webserver ESP8266 doesn’t work (+ Serial monitor doesn’t print)

Tags: php, html, arduino, webserver, esp8266

Hope you're doing fine!
I'm starting to learn about setting up WebServers on ESP8266, so, I'm developing this small project to start into it.

Basically, it's a WebServer with my ESP8266 working as a AP, where I input an HTML form with 6 input values that I'll receive on my ESP8266.

At this point, I've 2 big problems:

1st and most important, the server, the HTML script, & the AP work well overall, since once I upload the code on the ESP8266, and connect to the AP, I can access the form with no issues ( http://192.168.4.1/ ). The problem comes when I input the values and click "SET" to submit them, because it just prints: Not found: /action_page.php

I don't know where's the issue, I tried setting some code lines to redirect the acces if the server is not found, but it didn't even accessed the main page.

2nd, my serial monitor doesn't print any line in this code, with other codes, it prints normally, but this one doen't do it. So I don't know wat I'm doing wrong.

I'll appreciate any advice, thanks in advance! This is my current code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

String backmsg = "";

const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <title>ESP Input Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>

<h1  style='text-align:center;'> <br><br> WEBSERVER AP TEST <br><br> </h1>
<h2  style='text-align:center;'>1ST VERSION <br><br> </h2> 

<h3  style='text-align:center;'> 1ST SET: <br></h3>
<h3  style='text-align:center;'>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="one">ONE:</label>
      <input type="number" id="one" name="one" min="1" max="99">

      <label for="two"> &thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp; TWO:</label>
      <input type="number" id="two" name="two" min="1" max="99">

      <label for="thr"> &thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp; THR:</label>
      <input type="number" id="thr" name="thr" min="1" max="99"><br><br>      
  </h3>   


<h3  style='text-align:center;'> 2ND SET: <br></h3>
<h3  style='text-align:center;'>  
      <label for="fou">FOU:</label>
      <input type="number" id="fou" name="fou" min="1" max="99">
  
      <label for="fiv"> &thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp; FIV:</label>
      <input type="number" id="fiv" name="fiv" min="1" max="99">
  
      <label for="six"> &thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp; SIX:</label>
      <input type="number" id="six" name="six" min="1" max="99"><br><br>  <br><br>
    
    <input type="submit" value="SET">  
    </form>
  </h3>
  
</body></html>
)=====";

String pageend = "<br><br><a href='/'><button class='button'>Regresar</button></a></body></html>";


//SSID and Password of your WiFi router
const char* ssid     = "abcdefg";
const char* password = "1234567890";

ESP8266WebServer server(80); //Server on port 80

//When the page is opened
void handleRoot() {
 String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
}

//When submit is pressed
void handleForm() {
 String onev = server.arg("one"); 
 String twov = server.arg("two");
 String thrv = server.arg("thr");
 String fouv = server.arg("fou");
 String fivv = server.arg("fiv"); 
 String sixv = server.arg("six");


 String eeee =  onev + ":" +  twov + ":" +  thrv;
 String ffff =  fouv + "/" +  fivv + "/" +  sixv;
Serial.println(eeee);
Serial.println(ffff);
backmsg = "1st SET: " + eeee + "<br><br>" + "2nd SET: " + ffff + "<br><br>";

 String s = "<a href='/'> Go Back </a>";
 server.send(200, "text/html", backmsg + pageend + s); //Send web page
}


//SETUP
void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(100); 
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); 
    WiFi.softAP(ssid,password); 
    Serial.print("Access Point is Created with SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("Access Point IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

  server.on("/", handleRoot);      
  server.on("/action_page", handleForm); 
  server.begin();                  
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}


//LOOP
void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();       
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any PHP code?

Comment: when i click submit after filling the form on the web server, it goes to a blank page that says: Not found: /action_page.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is submitting the form to `/action_page.php` but your web server is handling `/action_page`. You need to pick one and be consistent when you use it.

Since you're not actually using PHP I'd recommend changing the form to:

```
  <form action="/action_page">
```